# How to remove the comma (,) while printing elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing

I would like to print individual elements of a list separating with commas using `for` loop.

```
numbers = ['23','44','76','89']
for i in numbers:
    print(i, end=",")
```

I see the output like this:

```
23,44,76,89,
```

How do I remove the last comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `join()` function:

```
numbers = ['23','44','76','89']
output = ','.join(numbers)
print(output)  # 23,44,76,89
```

If you want to use a loop, try:

```
numbers = ['23','44','76','89']
output = ""
for i in numbers:
    if output != "":
        output += ","
    output += i
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = ['23','44','76','89']
print(*numbers, sep=",") 
# Only for printing other wise you can use join function
```

Output

```
23,44,76,89
```

With for loop

```
numbers = ['23','44','76','89']
for i,v in enumerate(numbers):
    if i != len(numbers)-1:
        end = ','
    else:
        end = ''
    print(v,end=end)
```